# Multiple future call in single transaction

Tags: salesforce, future, apex

We are facing DUPLICATE_VALUE error while assigning permission set .
We are having 1 future method called from event trigger and another from user trigger.
for salesforce internal users its working fine , because that time event trigger is not triggering.
But for community user both future method executing in same transaction.
So basically
futurePermissionSetAssignment1 executes from UserTrigger , so it assign permission set
futurePermissionSetAssignment2 executes after futurePermissionSetAssignment1 , although we are verifying if permission is not assigned to user already but it didnt take result of futurePermissionSetAssignment1.
Experts please guide if it can be handle.
PS: I cant put community user check.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is bit messy and some code samples would help.
If it looks like you have parallel execution problem (operation A running a query, deciding to do X, in meantime operation B changes the state faster and A will fail because it works on old query results)...

You could do your thing as "save what you can" with `Database.insert(myAssignments, false);`: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm

Have a look at record locking with "[FOR UPDATE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm)". If both your futures start with say `SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN :... FOR UPDATE` they should detect a lock and one will wait for the other to finish (or will fail after 10 seconds)